# How to insert a data into a MySQL database via a variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I am trying to insert values defined in javascript at the start of the program. But it does not like me trying to insert variables, instead, I should enter the raw name.

This is the error code:

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'

I am using a SQL database and javascript to interact with it. The value has been defined with a variable beforehand.

```
var username = "Mark Graham"
var password = 13.00

con.connect(function(err) {
    var username = "Mark Graham"
    var password = 13.00 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO staff (name, hours) VALUES (username, password)";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
});
```

It should insert Mark Graham into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Implements a ORM, Sequelize or use

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO staff (name, hours) VALUES (?, ?)', [YourVar,YourSecondVar], function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

or

```
connection.query({
  sql: 'INSERT INTO staff (name, hours) VALUES (?, ?)',
  timeout: 40000, // 40s
  values: [varOne,varTwo]
}, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```